how can we auto insert tables from sql file to mariadb container started by docker-compose?
I have Docker compose file as shown below: and DB_NAME is db_table
services:
  devcontainer:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    volumes:
      - ../.. :/code:cached
    network_mode: service:db
    command: sleep infinity

  db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    env_file: ".env"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${ALGORITHM}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_NAME}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - mysql-db-data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./${DB_NAME}.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/${DB_NAME}.sql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

volumes:
  mysql-db-data:

I logged into the db container and I saw that the file db_table.sql has been copied to /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d folder. I was hoping it will automatically sourced into the container when it is started but when I show tables of the specific db name I don;t see anything.

Check permissions created on the table in the container. I remember running in to similar issue a while ago but cannot remember exact fix. Also, you need to map folder to initdb.d folder. Not .sql mapping like you have.

I just saw this message in the log, but its a warning though mysql.5.7 should work I doubt?
[Warning] 'default-authentication-plugin' is MySQL 5.6 / 5.7 compatible option. To be implemented in later versions.
